# How to get started in Java Game Programming?

Tags: java

As I try to program a game, I can't do virtually anything(because I really don't know what do do although I know the basics in Java), except if I look at tutorials.
I'd like to ask you, professional game programmers, how to actually learn game development without reading tutorials because those don't really teach a lot.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

First great step is to finish learning Java. You want to know more than just basics. After that (or while you're learning) you should get around to coding your first easy game like Tetris, Breakout or Pong. Don't look for more information about how to do it, these games are recommended for a reason, they're easy to program (relatively speaking) and you should be able to code them yourself.

[You probably want to read this.](http://web.archive.org/web/20051104034215/www.lupinegames.com/articles/path_to_dev.html)

After that, there are [general resource sites availible](http://www-cs-students.stanford.edu/~amitp/gameprog.html).

And books like **Game Engine Architecture** by Jason Gregory. Most books about making games deal in C++. But if you can code in Java, you'll be able to take most out of them anyway.